# HTML/CSS Mobile compatibility

Tags: html, css

A few days ago I started learning HTML / CSS in my spare time and programming my own test website. At some point I encountered a problem when I tried to visit my website on my smartphone. Here [Here you can see that the Picture is shifted above the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i23IM.png).

Everything works fine on the desktop, but as you can see, it has moved on the mobile device. I tried several methods, but none of them resolved the problem. Since I just started, I have no other ideas.

I do not want to post all my code, so the problem is [here](http://domenicmalz.de/About_me.html)

thank you in advance

Comment: What's the actual question? What are you going to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not only related to mobile I'm afraid.
That is what happens when you float, the container element loses its layout. To fix it you just need to give it back applying for example an `overflow: hidden`.

But I suppose you want to still have the img on the right of the Personal Data, for that you have to put the image inside the same container, applying the `overflow: hidden`.
Just like this:

```css
/*SCHRIFTART*/

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Levenim MT';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: local('Levenim MT'), url('ufonts.com_levenim-mt.woff') format('woff');
}


/*ALLGEMEIN*/


* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;


}

/* CONTENT */

#PB-Bild {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right:7.5px;
}

#Information {
overflow:hidden;
    height: 30%;
    width: 98%;
    border: 7px outset grey;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
    padding-left: 5px;
    color:darkblue;
}

.was {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight:900;
}
p.was::first-letter {
    color:brown;
    font-size:160%;
}

.was {
    font-family:Arial;
    color: black;
}

.uText {
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:ivory;
    font-size:120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Information">
<img id="PB-Bild" src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x350">
    <p class="was">Name:</p>
    Domenic Malz <br>
    <p class="was">Alter:</p>
    16 Jahre <br>
    <p class="was">Geboren am:</p>
    29.04.2002  <br>
    <p class="was">Wohnort:</p>
    Berlin <br>
    <p class="was">E-Mail</p>
    postfach@domenicmalz.de <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are bringing is known as responsiveness. There are many ways to make your website responsive, first thing I noticed when looking at your code, in your css you are making use of "px" values, they are pixel values meaning they are not scaling with the size of the screen. You should familiarise yourself with more responsive values such as "vw" and "vh" that do scale according to the size of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a few properties to `#banner2`, you can ensure the background does not auto scale.

```css
#banner2 {
  …
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

[image]